# Validation Rule : Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: validation-rule

```
AND
(Sync_to_system__c
,OR(CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '\\')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '/')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , ':')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '<')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '>')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '|')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '*')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '?')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '+')
,CONTAINS(Job_Number__c '#')
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '"')
,BEGINS(Job_Name__c, ' ')
,(RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1)=' ')
,(RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1)='.')))
```

Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

I must be missing something really obvious but i put it into notepad++ and all the )'s look like they line up just fine,

Sync_to_system__c is a checkbox
so I want to check that the box is checked and the job name has something like these.

Comment: You're missing a comma in `CONTAINS(Job_Number__c '#')`.  Missing commas typically result in that misleading error about the parenthesis.

Comment: @DavidCheng omg thankyou i knew it was somethign stupid thatt i missed

Comment: To anyone who wants to downvote this... don't. It's a perfectly valid question, well formatted and reproducible.

Comment: If it's a `Validation Rule`, you should *really* just use **`REGEX`**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `,` at `Job_Number__c`

```
,CONTAINS(Job_Number__c '#')
```

Should be

```
,CONTAINS(Job_Number__c, '#')
```

Answer (score 5):

Treating validation formulas like they were normal code and applying indentation tends to really help out on issues like this.

Doing that would look like this

```
AND(
    Sync_to_system__c,
    OR(
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '\\'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '/'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , ':'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '<'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '>'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '|'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '*'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '?'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '+'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Number__c '#'),
        CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '"'),
        BEGINS(Job_Name__c, ' '),
        (
            RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1) = ' '
        ),
        (
            RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1) = '.'
        )
    )
)
```

That doesn't seem to indicate anything wrong with parenthesis, but there is an issue with the `CONTAINS(Job_Number__c '#'),` part.

You're missing a comma in between the arguments to that call to CONTAINS. It's true that it's not a parenthesis, but syntax errors in formulas have a tendency to cascade to generate other issues in the end.

Comment: also worth noting that when I plugged this into a validation rule in a sandbox of mine (replacing the fields with ones that I actually had), the `check syntax` button did highlight the bit of the formula that was the issue(`'#'`)

Answer (score 3):

You can heavily optimize this code with REGEX, not to mention some of your conditions are nonsensical, specifically, a field cannot start with or end with a space character. Here's a revised version:

```
Sync_to_system__c && REGEX(Job_Name__c, '(.*(\\.$))|(.*[\\/:<>|*?+#].*)')
```

Comment: thanks I will test this out

Comment: Main reason I don't use regex much in validation rules is because they are a strange variant of their own and very hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

AND(
Sync_to_system__c,
OR(
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '\'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '/'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , ':'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '<'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '>'),
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '|'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '*'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '?'),
,CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '+'),
CONTAINS(Job_Number__c '#'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '"'),
BEGINS(Job_Name__c, ' '),
RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1)=' ',
RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1)='.'
)
)

Answer (score 0):

Yikes!  Well that looked hideous...  but it my defense I wrote it using my phone

Try this

```
AND( 
Sync_to_system__c, 
OR( 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '\'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '/'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , ':'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '<'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '>'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '|'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '*'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '?'),
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '+'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Number__c '#'), 
CONTAINS(Job_Name__c , '"'), 
BEGINS(Job_Name__c, ' '), 
RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1)=' ', 
RIGHT(Job_Name__c, 1)='.' 
))
```

Comment: 1) You should have edited your original answer rather than post an additional answer, so you should now delete one of them. If both of your answers are not the same, you can make a note in one answer as to their differences. 2) Your answer will give the same error as the original because it contains the same syntax issue *[see both Casper Harmer's and Derek F's answers]*. It appears that all you did was move the commas in the OPs code from the beginning of the line to the end of the previous line. This makes no functional difference - only aesthetic difference.